# Creating Temp Variables within Queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to be able to create a temp variable within a query--not a stored proc nor function-- which will not need to be declared and set so that I don't need to pass the query parameters when I call it.

Trying to work toward this:

```
   Select field1,
       tempvariable=2+2,
       newlycreatedfield=tempvariable*existingfield
From
       table
```

Away from this:

```
DECLARE @tempvariable
SET @tempvariable = 2+2
Select field1,
       newlycreatedfield=@tempvariable*existingfield
From
       table
```

Thank you for your time

I may have overcomplicated the example; more simply, the following gives the Invalid Column Name QID

```
Select
QID = 1+1
THN = QID + 1
```

If this is housed in a query, is there a workaround?

Comment: is there a reason you dont want to use a stored procedure?

Comment: if i had it to do over, I probably would, but these few lines sit in lines of thousands of other calcs and such in a much larger query. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
SELECT field1, tv.tempvariable,
       (tv.tempvariable*existingfield) AS newlycreatedfield
FROM table1
INNER JOIN (SELECT 2+2 AS tempvariable) AS tv
```

See SQLFIDDLE : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b0724/8/0

And to refer at your simplified example :

```
SELECT var.QID,
(var.QID + 1) AS THN
FROM (SELECT 1+1 as QID) AS var
```

See SQLFIDDLE : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/19140/0

Comment: perfect. 
I ended up using the first example, but my query forced me to join it to something, so I just did, " ON 1=1 ".

Answer (score 3):

### You can avoid derived tables and subqueries if you do a "hidden" assignment as a part of a complex concat_ws expression

Since the assignment is part of the expression of the ultimate desired value for the column, as opposed to sitting in its own column, you don't have to worry about whether MySQL will evaluate it in the correct order.  Needless to say, if you want to use the temp var in multiple columns, then all bets are off :-/

*caveat: I did this in MySQL 5.1.73; things might have changed in later versions*

I wrap everything in **concat_ws** because it coalesces null args to empty strings, whereas concat does not.

I wrap the assignment to the var **@stamp** in an **if** so that it is "consumed" instead of becoming an arg to be concatenated. As a side note, I have guaranteed elsewhere that u.status_timestamp is populated when the user record is first created.  Then @stamp is used in two places in **date_format**, both as the date to be formatted and in the nested if to select which format to use.  The final concat is an hour range "h-h" which I have guaranteed elsewhere to exist if the c record exists, otherwise its null return is coalesced by the outer concat_ws as mentioned above.

```
SELECT
concat_ws( '', if( @stamp := ifnull( cs.checkin_stamp, u.status_timestamp ), '', '' ),
  date_format( @stamp, if( timestampdiff( day, @stamp, now() )<120, '%a %b %e', "%b %e %Y" )),
  concat( ' ', time_format( cs.start, '%l' ), '-', time_format( cs.end, '%l' )) 
) AS as_of
FROM dbi_user AS u LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT c.u_id, c.checkin_stamp, s.start, s.end FROM dbi_claim AS c LEFT JOIN
  dbi_shift AS s ON(c.shift_id=s.id) ORDER BY c.u_id, c.checkin_stamp DESC) AS cs
ON (cs.u_id=u.id) WHERE u.status='active' GROUP BY u.id ;
```

A final note: while I happen to be using a derived table in this example, it is only because of the requirement to get the latest claim record and its associated shift record for each user.  You probably won't need a derived table if a complex join is not involved in the computation of your temp var.  This can be demonstrated by going to the first fiddle in @Fabien TheSolution's answer and changing the right hand query to

```
Select field1, concat_ws( '', if(@tempvariable := 2+2,'','') ,
       @tempvariable*existingfield ) as newlycreatedfield
from table1
```

Likewise the second fiddle (which appears to be broken) would have a right hand side of

```
SELECT concat_ws( '', if(@QID := 2+2,'',''), @QID + 1) AS THN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with subqueries:

```
Select field1, tempvariable,
       (tempvariable*existingfield) as newlycreatedfield
from (select t.*, (2+2) as tempvariable
      from table t
     ) t;
```

Unfortunately, MySQL has a tendency to actually instantiate (i.e. create) a derived table for the subquery.  Most other databases are smart enough to avoid this.

You can gamble that the following will work:

```
Select field1, (@tempvariable := 2+2) as tempvariable,
       (@tempvariable*existingfield) as newlycreatedfield
From table t;
```

This is a gamble, because MySQL does not guarantee that the second argument is evaluated before the third.  It seems to work in practice, but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: That's interesting and helpful. I appreciate your response.

Comment: Second gamble throws a "Must Declare the Scalar Variable tempvariable" error.

Comment: And the first throws an "invalid column name"

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
SET @sum = 4 + 7;
SELECT @sum;
```

Output:

```
+------+
| @sum |
+------+
|   11 |
+------+
```

[source](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mysql-cookbook-2nd/059652708X/ch01s27.html)

Comment: I'm guessing the OP might want to have the side effect of incrementing the temp var for each of the subsequent rows that the select will be returning from the table.