# MySQL permissions -- can't create functions without user permission

Tags: mysql, function, permissions, subquery, prepared-statement

I would like to use a function like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION substr_beginning_end (long_text text, substr_beginning VARCHAR(50), substr_end VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS VARCHAR(2000) DETERMINISTIC

RETURN SUBSTR(long_text, 
        POSITION(substr_beginning IN long_text) + LENGTH(substr_beginning),
        LOCATE(substr_end, long_text, POSITION(substr_beginning IN long_text))-POSITION(substr_beginning IN long_text) - LENGTH(substr_beginning)
        );
```

But I have only execution privileges on the database and procedures.

Is there a way to just use a function without having permissions for creating such a function in the database?

Thanks.

Comment: No, you can't use a function if it's not defined, and you can't define a function if you don't have permission to create functions. There's no such thing as temporary or local functions that aren't saved in the DB.

Comment: @Barmar there is no other way you have in mind? like using sth weird like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477500/creating-temp-variables-within-queries
in each field copying the same "function" but defining the parameters before with a concat_ws function. (I did not success in doing like that, but may be you know a "better" way). Thanks

Comment: The assignment to the temp variable will just contain the long `SUBSTR(...)` expression you're trying to avoid writing in the query. What's the point of that?

Comment: @Barmar I just wanted to select different features from json files (request and response), but it was much more complicated to replace with specific text on each part of the function, so I did like it is shown in the following post (I answered to myself :s)

Comment: I'm talking about writing repeatedly different queries with the same structure

Answer (score 0):

Since I got no answers but a comment, I made the following based on this link [Creating Temp Variables within Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477500/creating-temp-variables-within-queries):

```
SELECT   
         CONCAT_WS( if(@campo1_substr_beginning := 'feature01":"', '',''), 
                    if(@campo1_substr_end := '",', '',''), 
         SUBSTR(request, POSITION(@campo1_substr_beginning IN request) + LENGTH(@campo1_substr_beginning), 
                  LOCATE(@campo1_substr_end, request, POSITION(@campo1_substr_beginning IN request)) 
                        - POSITION(@campo1_substr_beginning IN request) 
                        - LENGTH(@campo1_substr_beginning)
                 ) ) AS 'campo1',
         CONCAT_WS( if(@campo3_substr_beginning := '"feature02":', '',''), 
                    if(@campo3_substr_end := ',', '',''), 
         SUBSTR(request, POSITION(@campo3_substr_beginning IN request) + LENGTH(@campo3_substr_beginning), 
                  LOCATE(@campo3_substr_end, request, POSITION(@campo3_substr_beginning IN request)) 
                        - POSITION(@campo3_substr_beginning IN request) 
                        - LENGTH(@campo3_substr_beginning)
                 ) ) AS 'campo3',
             request,
             response
FROM event_log elog
WHERE 
    ....
```

Maybe if somebody thinks of a better way that does not require to rename the variables for each field (campo1_substr.... and campo2_substr...) just let me know!

Thanks.